# Call a Future method for limited time

Tags: dart

TL;DR: I want to call a Future method. I have limited amount of time. In this lifespan I can call this method any number of times. But, after the time finishes, no more calls.

Assume the following code:

```dart
Future<int> getValue() async {
  int res = await someComputation();
  return res;
}

void processTask() {
  int maxCalls = 500; // pre-determined
  int timeLimit = 1500; // in milliseconds

  // Question from here...

  // Call `getValue()` at max `maxCalls` times.
  // But, this process should be done until `timeLimit`.
  // If `timeLimit` is hit, don't call `getValue()` anymore... 
}
```

How to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using a [Stopwatch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html), you should start the stopwatch before the loop and check inside the loop if the time is exceeded or not:

```dart
...
var stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();

for (var i = 0; i < maxCalls; i++)
{
  if (stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds => timeLimit) {
    break;
  }
  getValue();
}
stopwatch.stop();
```